# Is this valid in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, show

I am showing three divs using jquery using this,

```
$("#ImageButtonDiv").show();
$("#ResultsDiv").show();
$("#PagerDown").show();
```

Is my following statement valid?

`$("#ImageButtonDiv #ResultsDiv #PagerDown").show();`

Any suggestion...

Comment: Chendur: that would look for `#PagerDown` inside `#ResultsDiv` inside `#ImageButtonDiv`. selectors are comma-separated in jQuery, as they are in CSS. GenericTypeTea's version is the way to go

Comment: @David Hedlund i got your point...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You do this instead:

```
$("#ImageButtonDiv, #ResultsDiv, #PagerDown").show();
```

When using [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), you much separate each with a comma `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because it's possible:

```
$("#ImageButtonDiv #ResultsDiv #PagerDown".split(' ').join(',')).show();
```

But, returning to seriousness, sticking to a **D.R.Y.** I would use a `class` for all those elements and just call

```
$('.my_beautiful_class').show();
```

Comment: Are you missing a close bracket there?

Comment: Why would anyone do that?! Cool anyway :)

Comment: @GenericTypeTea: nope, should be fine.
@Makram: I don't have a clue actually, maybe in a land before time, some backend developer sent a string with identifiers sepperated with whitespaces? I don't know :)